# Can two Squarespace websites be of the same subdomain, with a slash

Tags: dns, web-deployment, squarespace, webmin, virtualmin

so my issue is as follows:
I have a website, on one language pointing to a site subdomain.domain.com. I added CNAME records and it points perfectly. I now have another squarespace page that is the clone of the other one, only in a different language. Is there a way to point it to subdomain.domain.com/en , for example, and how would one go about doing this thru squarespace and my hosting sites webmin.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use same subdomain for more than once. But as you own, and have access to that domain you can make different subdomain. So it can be: subdomain.domain.com and ensubdomain.domain.com or even you can have subdomain of subdomain en.subdomain.domain.com. You are probably aware where it goes. You can have something like:  you.can.go.as.far.as.you.need.or.you.want.domain.com. ( be aware that you need to check with host first, what is included in your package or maybe do you have some limits)